# Why can't I load files from a folder named 'users'?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, directory, naming

I am developing a MEAN app. My Angular folder structure is the following:
[image]

and get the following errors on my app:
[image]

but when I rename the 'users' folder to anything else, like 'user', it works:
[image]
[image]

why is that?

**EDIT:**

app.js as requeseted:

```
var mainModuleName = 'mean';

var mainModule = angular.module(mainModuleName, ['ngRoute', 'example', 'users']);

mainModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);

if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash - '#!';

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, [mainModuleName]);
});
```

Comment: can you post your app.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bwah! Silly me.

I have a method as my API that is at the following:

http://localhost:3000/users

so instead of serving files, it reaches for the API and that is also why Mongoose throws an error there in the console picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the second argument for angular.module in your first case.  You should have

```
angular.module('users',[]).factory('auth',[auth]);
```

Because you don't have the brackets, you're not actually creating a new instance of user and that's where the error is coming from.

This link might help
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: that would actually collide with my already defined module. i don't think this is angular's issue though